# PDF and CDF distribution looking for feedback on my work

Tags: probability-distributions

Given $$X_i ∼ Uniform[0, 1] $$for $$i = 1, .., n.$$
What is the distribution of $$M := min(X_1, ...., X_n)?$$
You may assume that $$X_1,X_2, ... ,X_n are independent.$$
My solution:
$$X_1 ∼U [0,1]$$
$$PDF f(x)=1, 0≤ x≤ 1$$
$$ F(x)= \int_0^{x} f_x(x)\,dx$$
$$=\int_0^{x} 1\,dx$$
$$x, 0≤ x≤ 1$$
**CDF of min
**$$= 1-[1-x]^n $$
PDF of min
$$=n(1-x)^{n-1}$$****

This is my solutions, and just wanted to check my answers with you guys

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Please be nicer to user29. They are new to Math StackExchange.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @William I want to know if my solutions for cdf and pdf are correct

Comment: This is a correct answer but as a solution I would want to see a presentation of the main idea that the min is bigger than x if and only if all are bigger than x. So a few more lines of development would be useful.